# How do I use markdown imports in CSS (Astro)

Tags: markdown, astrojs

I have been trying to import frontmatter into css with Astro and cannot figure out how to put it into the css. I need it to work this way because I am trying to be able to update a background image for each item through the markdown file.

Card.astro

```
---
const allvideos = await Astro.glob("../content/videos/*.md");
---

{
  allvideos.map((video) => (
    <div class="mb-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="h-100 p-5 text-light rounded-3 background">
        <h2>{video.frontmatter.name}</h2>
        <p>{video.frontmatter.desc}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" type="button" href={video.frontmatter.link} target="_blank">Watch Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))
}

<style>
  .background {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgb(24, 24, 24, 0.8)),
      url(../images/{video.frontmatter.image});
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
</style>
```

Markdown File

```
---
name: "Name"
desc: "Description"
link: link
image: imagename.webp
---
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables from frontmatter to CSS you can use Astro’s [`define-vars` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#definevars).

In a simple example:

```
---
const image = "image.png";
---

<div class="background" />

<style define:vars={{ bgImage: `url(../images/${image})` }}>
  .background {
    background: var(--bgImage);
  }
</style>
```

Because you want to set a different image for each item in the loop, to use `define:vars` you would need to create a component you use inside the loop:

```
---
// Card.astro

interface Props {
  name: string;
  desc: string;
  link: string;
  image: string;
}

const { image, name, desc, link } = Astro.props;
---

<div class="mb-4 col-md-6">
  <div class="h-100 p-5 text-light rounded-3 background">
    <h2>{name}</h2>
    <p>{desc}</p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" type="button" href={link} target="_blank">Watch Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

<style define:vars={{ bgImage: `url(../images/${image})` }}>
  .background {
    min-height: 100%;
    background:
      linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
      rgb(24, 24, 24, 0.8)),
      var(--bgImage);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
</style>
```

Then use the component in the loop in your template:

```
---
import Card from '../Card.astro';
const allvideos = await Astro.glob("../content/videos/*.md");
---

{
  allvideos.map((video) => <Card {...video.frontmatter} />)
}
```

---

**N.B.** The approach you’re using to create the image URLs may not work depending on how you’re storing the images in your project. Check out [Astro’s image docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/) for details about resolving and importing images.